# Why Managed Properties for our site columns are not mapped to any crawl property

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, administration, crawled-property, search-schema

I have created the following site columns inside our root site collection:

[image]

and we added some test data inside the related list which have the above site content type and site columns. after 24 hours I checked our Search Schema >> Managed Properties >> I found that 3 managed properties were already created for us repressing these columns internal names (ContactCustomerName = ContactEmail + ContactLastName):

[image]

but there is not any crawl property linked to them. Can anyone advice on this weird case please?

Answer (score 1):

That is just the way it is now with SharePoint online. If you click into one of the automatically created managed properties you'll see a banner at the top that says:

> **Automatically created managed property.** Search automatically created
> the CONTACTEMAILOWSTEXT managed property, but can't display the actual
> automatic settings and mappings here. Instead it displays all settings
> as disabled, and no mappings. If you add a crawled property mapping
> here, search adds it to the automatic mappings. Learn how you can see
> which crawled property was automatically mapped to this managed
> property. If you change a setting here, search overwrites all the
> automatic settings and mappings with those displayed here.

They work and will have data, but you won't see it in the schema.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. so is there any harm if i manually add/map the related crawl properties? or it is not recommended to touch those automatically created managed properties?

Comment: also in my case i can not see any banner at top!

Comment: Strange that you don't get the warning message. Have your tried a query to see if the values are in the automatically created managed properties? I wouldn't recommend remapping them if they are already working.

Comment: which query i can use?